# Formatting NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having some trouble comparing `NSDate` as they have a different format.

From one side I have a `NSDate` who looks like this:

```
2013-12-05T10:12:00.120Z
```

And from the other side I have another NSDate that looks this way:

```
2013-12-01 10:1200 +00000
```

My question is, how could I make the first `NSDate` look like the 2nd one?
And more important, what does 120Z mean? I guess it's the timezone, but I am not really sure of it.
By the way, is it there any way to can format the `NSDate's` and updating the time respecting the timezone hour difference?

Thanks a lot!

**EDITED:**

To get the 1st NSDate I do the following (I need to get the last opened date of a file):

```
MDItemRef item = MDItemCreate(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)filePath);
NSDate *date = (NSDate*)CFBridgingRelease(MDItemCopyAttribute(item,
kMDItemLastUsedDate));
```

And to get the 2nd NSDate I do the following:

```
 NSDate* threeDaysAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-259200];
```

Comment: So you have two NSStrings that each represent a date and time but using a different format and what you want to do is to convert them to NSDate objects?

Comment: Both are NSDates, just I get one this way: NSDate* threeDaysAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-259200]; and I get the other calling to CFBridgingRelease. This is why I get two different formats. And when try to compare them I get an error

Comment: NSDates don't have formats. Can you show how the dates are created and how you compare them?

Comment: *"what does 120Z mean?"* - 10:12:00.120 is the time and 120 is the milliseconds part of it. Z stands for "Zulu" which is the same as GMT.

Comment: Thanks a lot to everybody, I have just updated my question to be easier to understand everything

Comment: I guess that `259200` are supposed to be 3 days. But this can be wrong, due to Daylight Saving Time. You should definitely try to learn some proper calendar calculations. great WWDC video: [Performing Calendar Calculations](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=117)

Answer (score 0):

Convert both the dateStrings to `NSDate` and then you can easily compare the dateObjects.

For converting string to date  thing you need :

[NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

For comparing two dates :

```
resultant = [dateOne compare:dateTwo]
```

`resultant` can be  `NSOrderedAscending` or `NSOrderedSame` or `NSOrderedDescending`.

Comment: Both are NSDates, just I get one this way: NSDate* threeDaysAgo = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-259200]; and I get the other calling to CFBridgingRelease. This is why I get two different formats. And when try to compare them I get an error

Comment: both cant be date. you can check by printing its class name. Dates have a defuault format, while you are saying something differnt

Comment: thanks a lot, I have just updated my question, maybe will be easier to understand it now. And yes, both are NSDates and I have printed them and have different formats

Answer (score 0):

You have a misunderstanding of what an `NSDate` is.  It is not "in a format" at all, but is actually a wrapper around a a `double` which is the number of seconds since Jan 1st 1970 12:00am UTC.  You can compare your two dates directly to see which one is the earlier.  However, if you are trying to compare for equality, it's more tricky.  If you want to see if they are within one minute of each other, you can do something like

```
 [date1 timeIntervalSinceDate: date2] < 60.0;
```